How do pool keys for Pump.fun tokens that migrated to Raydium differ from standard AMM pool tokens?
I was observing some tokens that are being launched using onProgramAccountChange wss method and I noticed that pool state keys for pump.fun tokens that migrated to Raydium are different than normal tokens in AMM pool.
For example, I saw that baseMint and quoteMint are switched and I am wondering what else is different (baseVault, baseDecimals, etc) and how can these values be modified to correctly prepare and calculate computeAmountOut using Raydium SDK.
I tried switching all properties that have base and quote in the property name, but swap is failing. If I just switch baseMint and quoteMint, buying works, but selling does not.
I am talking about LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4 in: https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk/blob/master/src/liquidity/layout.ts
Here is a comparison of pool keys of pump.fun token (on the left) and standard AMM pool token (on the right) - I just replaced baseMint and quoteMint of the pump fun token.

Thanks for the help.

pump.fun uses raydium_amm_idl.json, you can find it here for example https://github.com/chainstacklabs/pump-fun-bot/tree/main/idl
it's also somewhere in the Raydium repos, but I can't remember right away. They have two or three different ones — for limit orders & so on. Hence the difference.
For pump.fun specifically, here's a script I created that listens to the migrations from pump.fun to the Raydium AMM and prints the token address and the new liquidity pool address.
See Listening to pump.fun migrations to Raydium.
